# RocksDB: Too many SST files of very small size

Tags: java, rocksdb

I am using RocksDBJava after running the service for sometime I can see the "Too many open files" exception. Digging through the previous issue mentioned on the portal I found out that it is because of system limitation of opening a maximum number of files.
When I check the directory, which the rocksDB is using, I noticed there is over 100K sst files of 1KB size, and this can be the reason of the given error.
I wanted to know is there any way by which we can configure the rocksDB to generate SST files of large size, so that the total number of files created is minimum and we can avoid this error.

Also in my current project there are many read threads and one write thread, and I open and close the connection (using `RocksDB.open()` and `RocksDB.close()`) before reading or writing to the rocksDB.

Answer (score 3):

You can use these two options to create larger SST files: `target_file_size_base` and `target_file_size_multiplier`. See [the doc](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/RocksDB-Tuning-Guide) for details.

Also, you can use the `max_open_files` option to limit the number of files that RocksDB can open. However, in order to get good performance, I suggest you increasing the system limitation on the max number of open files, and configure `max_open_files` to be `-1`.

Comment: Thanks, can you please help how can I set these values in JavaRocks.

Comment: I checked the API, but I couldn't found any way to set these value using java API.

Comment: @AmanSinghal It seems that Java API uses another naming rule: `org.rocksdb.Options`, `setTargetFileSizeBase`, `setTargetFileSizeMultiplier`, `setMaxOpenFiles`

Comment: Which version you checked, I am not able to find this method in 5.1.2 version.

Comment: Also, I checked the value of target_file_size_base in generated options file, it is showing as 67108864 value, which is very large, still I am not able to understand why it is creating too many sst files.

Comment: what I generally noticed is that with every new key in the column family it is creating a new sst file.

Comment: I checked this one: https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/master/java/src/main/java/org/rocksdb/Options.java

Comment: `with every new key in the column family it is creating a new sst file` That's strange, and I didn't get the problem before.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try setting a higher value for `write_buffer_size`
that should create fewer and larger SST files.

Comment: This seems to be a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score -1):

By default, when you call `RocksDB.open()` the RocksDB reads all WAL to recover the memtable, then do a `flush()` writing the memtable as an SST file. That's why you got so many small SST files.

To avoid this behaviour set option `avoid_flush_during_recovery` to true when openning DB. The Java version is named `avoidFlushDuringRecovery()`. Also, never call flush or do implicitly flush (such as createCheckpoint etc.) in your code.

See the code [here](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/master/include/rocksdb/options.h#L892-L899).